# Need to sort the pivot table based on the columns passed in index attribute . Its MultiIndex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot, pivot-table

Can't sort the pivot table based on the columns passed in index attribute in ascending order.
when the df is printed '**Deepthy**' comes first for column Name, I need '**aarathy**' to come first

[pls check this image while printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwgoF.png)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['aarathy', 'Deepthy','aarathy','aarathy'],'Ship': ['everest', 'Oasis of the Seas','everest','everest'],  'Tracking': ['TESTTRACK003', 'TESTTRACK008', 'TESTTRACK009','TESTTRACK005'],'Bag': ['123', '127', '129','121'],})

df=pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Name","Ship","Tracking","Bag"]).sort_index(axis=1,ascending=True)

I tried it by passing sort_values and sort_index(axis=1,ascending=True) but id doesn't works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You naeed convert values to lowercase and for first level of sorting use `key` parameter:

```
#helper column for run your code
df['new'] = 1

df=(pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Name","Ship","Tracking","Bag"])
       .sort_index(level=0,ascending=True, key=lambda x: x.str.lower()))
print (df)
                                            new
Name    Ship              Tracking     Bag     
aarathy everest           TESTTRACK003 123    1
                          TESTTRACK005 121    1
                          TESTTRACK009 129    1
Deepthy Oasis of the Seas TESTTRACK008 127    1
```